# Event onSeek - Abbort the seeking process

Tags: jquery, events, jwplayer, seek

is it possible to abbort the seek process?
My urls expires after 10 seconds so i must request a new url when the user click on seek.

```
onSeek: function(event)
{
     getFreshUrl({videoId:'XXXXX', action:get}, function(data)
     {
        jwplayer().load({file: data.url, start: event.offset});
     });
     // STOP SEEKING
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Comment: i'd like to know that too. i tried to find the default seek function inside the api (only for html5 mode ) but i did not success :(

Answer (score 0):

Its probably a bit late:

You're using a url that is already verified, and will stop working after x seconds.

Try using the verification url instead of the verified url ( so all the request while playing and seeking will be verified again ).

I don't see the response from the verification server / page, but for this to work it needs to be redirected.